# Is it safe to enable to allow apps from unknown sources?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, unknown-sources

I would like to install whatsapp on my Huawei android tablet  but get the message (as others have ) stating ' your device is not compatible'.

Searching the internet it seems that you can bypass things and get it installed. However it seems the only way to do it is to all apps from unknown sources. My problem is I am not happy in what you appear to be doing ie withdrawing security and allowing apps from unknown sources.

Does anyone know if it really is safeand will not allow the tablet to add peculiar and potentially other unwanted app

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are getting the file/APK from a reputable source, it should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Installing from unknown sources is by itself not dangerous - it just **allows you to do dangerous things**. Enabling it will be safe as long as you get the APK from a source you trust.

Just to be sure you can turn the option off after you have installed the custom APK. It doesn't affect things you already have installed, just the installation of and updates of new things.